# Keycloak 16.1.1: User with username 'admin' already added to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json'

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, keycloak

I'm trying to start keycloak for my java spring boot 3.1.4 backend app via docker compose. Here's my docker compose:

```yaml
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: banking_microservice_db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - db:/data/postgres
    networks:
      - keycloak-network
    restart: unless-stopped

  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: jboss/keycloak:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: INFO
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - keycloak-network
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  keycloak-network:

volumes:
  db:
```

When i run `docker compose up -d` i keep getting the error:

`2023-10-12 22:41:05 User with username 'admin' already added to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json'`

[image]

- I tried deleting images, containers and redownloading them again, same problem
- I tried using different versions of keycloak, same problem
- I tried changing `KEYCLOAK_USER`, `KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD`, same problem
- I tried commenting out those two ENV variables and restarting key cloak, same problem
- I tried deleting postgres db volume, same problem

What is the problem?

Comment: What is the other error on the image above?

Comment: @LejdiPrifti here are the full crash logs from docker https://pastebin.com/raw/gx36DXzr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed this issue. I couldn't any solution online. I fixed it by experimenting myself and trying stuff until it works.

I learned 4 important factors that need to be set for this to get fixed:

1. First of all this is the docker-compose.yml now:

```yaml
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: banking_microservice_db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/data/postgres
    networks:
      - keycloak-network
    restart: unless-stopped

  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: jboss/keycloak:latest
    ports:
      - "9990:8080"
      - "9991:8443"
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak_db
      DB_USER: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: root
      KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: INFO
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - keycloak-network
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  keycloak-network:

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

This part:

```yaml
# ...
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/data/postgres
# ...
```

was causing the most trouble.

- If this part DOES get set:

  - Keycloak container can NOT boot up, throwing the error i just explained in the original post.
  - BUT the banking-core microservice CAN boot up, because it can now connect to postgres via volume.
- If this part does NOT get set:

  - Keycloak container CAN boot up, without any errors.
  - BUT the banking-core microservice can NOT boot up, because now it can't connect to the postgres db since there's no volume mounted.

2. For some very strange reason, the volume for postgres db can NOT be anything other than `postgres-data`.

Before:

```yaml
# ...
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - db:/data/postgres
# ...


volumes:
  db:
```

After:

```yaml
# ...
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/data/postgres
# ...


volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

- If `db` is set -> keycloak container fails to boot.
- If `postgres-data` is set -> keycloak container boots up.

Don't know why this matters. If anyone knows, please explain.

3. Keycloak db username and password must be the same one that has been set on postgres, while database names can remain different:

Before:

```yaml
  postgres:
    # ...
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    # ...


  keycloak:
    # ...
    environment:
      # ...
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
    # ...
```

After:

```yaml
  postgres:
    # ...
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    # ...


  keycloak:
    # ...
    environment:
      # ...
      DB_USER: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: root
    # ...
```

The reason why i have a separate database `banking_microservice_db` and `keycloak_db` is because i want to use the first database only for my microservices while the second database gets used only by keycloak. Keycloak generates tens of tables and i dont want them to get mixed up with my own.

4. Final thing to do is to manually create a database before starting the docker compose:

```bash
docker exec -it postgres bash
psql -U postgres
CREATE DATABASE banking_microservice_db;
CREATE DATABASE keycloak_db;
```

Now everything should work fine.

You might have noticed that i changed docker compose a bit, but that's for better convenience for me and does not impact in solving this problem:

- I changed ports from `8080:8080` -> `9990:8080` for HTTP
- And added a new port `9991:8443` for SSL